# How to get the last update data from xml file in android?

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, xml

I'm developing an application about alert earthquakes. The information I get from an XML file and I want every time the XML file is updated with a new earthquake, this notifies the phone, even if the application is closed. How I can know the last earthquake, if I have the following XML structure? Maybe with an array?

```
<markers>
<marker lat="-4.33" lng="-80.38" mg="3.8" z="10" fecha="2014/09/11 19:22:26" detalle="true"/>
<marker lat="-3.68" lng="-78.03" mg="3.9" z="10" fecha="2014/09/11 05:22:52" detalle="true"/>
<marker lat="0.91" lng="-78.47" mg="3.5" z="10" fecha="2014/09/11 03:53:45" detalle="true"/>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your XML file stored? If its on a server, you can have the app ping your server every certain amount of time and pull the data if it is updated. This would require you to implement server logic as well.

An easier way would be to use a storage API like [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/) or [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/) that give you the functionality you want but they are not completely free.

**NOTE**: 
Google recommend to use `XmlPullParser`, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android.

[Here](http://www.kinvey.com/) are the full details

Comment: That's right, the XML file stored on a server. The last link is the same to first link.

Comment: Like I said, that is not an easy answer and nobody will post a full server architecture for you. You have to show exactly how you communicate with the server and where you are stuck and what errors you are getting and then we can help you. Also, the API's I suggested are good for practice and pretty easy to use